# UIButton in navigaton bar like Tweetbot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I would like to reproduce a Tweetbot like navigation bar.
I'm still searching if it's possible to place an `UIButton` in place of title in an `UINavigationBar` bar **and** to make it fits perfectly between right and left buttons like it is done in Tweetbot application.
When I try to do this, over a certain size the `self.navigationItem.titleView` is resized down automatically

Tell me if I miss something evident,
Thank you

I provide two screenshots to let you see what I'm talking about
[image: Button normal]
[image: Button hihlighted]

Answer (score 1):

They've probably rolled in their own implementation of `UINavigationBar` and/or `UINavigationController`. I guess it's not worth trying to hack UIKit that much, since it will be very fragile and not future-proof.

Comment: Fragility and future-proofness are not an issu to my mind. I'm still searching

Comment: I think you don't need to go that far. Subclassing these classes should be the last solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to the navigation item's title view property, which accepts an UIView, and since a UIButton is a subclass of an UIView this is not an issue.

Alternatively, if you are using storyboard, just drag a button to the center of the navigation bar, it's that easy.

```
// Create the button, and specify the type
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// Set the button's frame
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);

// Set your custom image for the button
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Set the button's action, which is the method that will be called when it is pressed
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Add the button to the navigation bar's title view
[self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:button];
```

SDK Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html

Comment: Add a button as a subview of titleView is not the problem. The problem is to make it fit perfectly between the left and right buttons

Comment: @gsempe I don't have the app myself, but I do not see why you can not just adjust the frame of the button dynamically.  The button is already centered in the title view, adjust the width to fit your needs

Comment: @gsempe It looks like some photoshop skills

Comment: The self.navigationItem.titleView frame is resized automatically and it seems out of developer control

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set autoresizesSubviews to YES on titleView, then set the correct autoresizing masks on the UIButton? If this doesn't work I suggest you to create your custom view subclass and override -layoutSubviews to fit your needs.